# Apply New Password Policy via GPO Gradually

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, password-policy

I want to make changes to the password policy in our domain (for example, include password complexity) but I want to apply it gradually, to some OU's or users group first. As far as I know the password enformcement are manage for the domain controllers, it is possible apply a different password policy for some users? Or the same seeting will be apply to all users when the DC's apply the GPO?

Regards,
Amedina

Comment: Remember that when you change the policy, new passwords will not be forced to follow the new policy until the old passwords expire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first answer was utter nonsense, sorry. Here we go:

If you are on Windows 2008 or higher (as you should), you can use [Fine-Grained Password Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc770394(v=ws.10)).

Using the "new" [Active Directory Administrative Center you can set these quite easily](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2013/05/29/step-by-step-enabling-and-using-fine-grained-password-policies-in-ad/).

The gist is:

1. Navigate to  -> System -> Password Settings Container
2. Create a new password policy
3. Set the users / groups to which it should be applied

Comment: man, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.